# Call MATLAB installed on network drive from Cygwin shell script

Tags: shell, cygwin, shell-script, matlab, network-drive

[MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab) is installed on a network drive, and I want to call it from a shell script.  The installed location is `\\apps\matlab2014b$\bin\win64\MATLAB.exe` in `P:\`. I am using Cygwin to run the shell scripts.  How can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried?  What problems are you having?  Can you run Windows `.exe` files on the local drive from Cygwin?  And it might be useful to state what operating system you are running.

Answer (score 0):

I used

'//apps/matlab2014b$/bin/win64/MATLAB.exe' -r filename

and it worked in my shell script. DONOT use .m in the filename above.